# Intersection points between a 3d segment and a bilinear surface

Tags: line, intersection, surface

Given a segment defined by 3d points `A` and `B`, and a surface defined by the four corners `P00`, `P01`, `P11`, `P10` (counter-clockwise, `P00` being lower left corner), and `t` the value defined in the interval `0.0 <= t <= 1.0` along the segment where the intersection occurs, how can I find all possible values of `t`?

In my use-case the surface is axis-aligned, meaning:

```
P00.x == P10.x, P01.x == P11.x, P00.y == P01.y, P10.y == P11.y
```

I tried using the parametric segment definition:

```
x = (Bx - Ax)t + Ax
y = (By - Ay)t + Ay
z = (Bz - Az)t + Az
```

Plus the surface definition:

```
P(x,y,z) = P(u,v) = (1-u)(1-v)P00 + (1-u)(v)P01 + (u)(1-v)P10 + (u)(v)P11
```

And try to equalize them and solve for t, but did not went very far simplifying the result.

Comment: "Unlike other surfaces, solving the ray-bilinear patch intersection with simple algebraic manipulations fails. We present a complete, efficient, robust, and graceful formulation to solve ray-bilinear patch intersections quickly." quoted from [Ray Bilinear Patch Intersection, S. D.Ramsey et al.](http://www.sci.utah.edu/~kpotter/publications/ramsey-2004-RBPI.pdf)

Comment: Good source, want to write an answer out of that comment?